# Download link in jsp doesn't work

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am using apache tomcat and i have some files in my system, I am creating links of these files with the below JSP code.

```
<%
File files = new File("/Users/user1/tests");
File[] fileList = files.listFiles();
for(int i=0; i<fileList.length;i++) {
    File f = fileList[i];
    out.println(i+". <a href='"+f.getAbsolutePath()+"' >"+f.getName()+"</a>");
}
%>
```

Now the links are generated fine, but when i click on these links apache is throwing 404 error. How can i make apache to access that folder.

Answer (score -1):

On local system if your file is in another directory except to current web directory You need to set full absolute path of file to download a file using `href`.

Syntax is:-

```
out.println(i+". <a href='file:///"+f.getAbsolutePath()+"' >"+f.getName()+"</a>");
```

Comment: it is showing clearly in the question that is is not windows.

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: lets try and guess `new File("/Users/user1/tests");`

Comment: a) who said I downvoted? b) why do you think the OP is using windows?

Comment: It is obvious that I am using Mac or linux, but it is Mac

Comment: how is that different to my answer?  Also, the OP was originally using getAbsolutePath, so your explanation does not make sense.

Comment: We need to put only 2 slashes after file: one slash is already coming from absolutePath() function, but now the problem comes in browser, it is showing "not able to load local resource" in its console

Comment: @SumitKumar Do one thing print this line in console and try to run it in browser manually. `file:///"+f.getAbsolutePath()+"' >"+f.getName()'

Comment: It didn't solve the issue so i have created a separate servlet to download the file. Thanks you all

Comment: @SumitKumar please close this question